# Data distribution while repartitioning RDD in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Consider the following snippet (running Spark 2.1 on Python 2.7):

```
nums = range(0, 10)

with SparkContext("local[2]") as sc:
    rdd = sc.parallelize(nums)
    print("Number of partitions: {}".format(rdd.getNumPartitions()))
    print("Partitions structure: {}".format(rdd.glom().collect()))

    rdd2 = rdd.repartition(5)
    print("Number of partitions: {}".format(rdd2.getNumPartitions()))
    print("Partitions structure: {}".format(rdd2.glom().collect()))
```

The output is:

```
Number of partitions: 2
Partitions structure: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

Number of partitions: 5
Partitions structure: [[], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [], [], []]
```

Why after repartitioning data was not distributed across all partitions?

Answer (score 0):

`repartition` in pyspark is `coalesce(numPartitions, shuffle=True)` ([see core code here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/330c3e33bd10f035f49cf3d13357eb2d6d90dabc/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L2041)) .i.e data is shuffled all across the network and partitioning is done in round robin fashion meaning, The first record goes to the first processing node, the second to the second processing node, but in your case since you only assigned `local[2]` i.e.  two (hypothetical) nodes, but my guess is spark was only able to get one one core from your local machine, so it put all values in that one particular node where the task ran.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't think that would be the case. This method works when using DataFrames (see https://hackernoon.com/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4) but fails on pure RDDs